Contract Reverted?
I was deploying WebAssembly (WASM) contracts on the Polkadot SDK version release-polkadot1.1.0. My codebase utilized unified address mapping. However, when I attempted to deploy the contract using the Substrate Contract UI, it returned an error: ContractReverted.Could anyone guide me through this.
